# Coulomb potential singularity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, atomic-physics, quantum-electrodynamics

When reading Gravity and Strings book by T. Ortín, I have come up with the following paragraph:

> *"if we solve Maxwell’s
> equations in vacuum imposing spherical symmetry and staticity, we find the Coulomb solution $A_μ = δ_{tμ}q/(4πr )$, which is singular at $r = 0$ and there the equations are not solved. However, one can add at $r = 0$ a singular source corresponding to a point-like electric charge. The Maxwell equations are then solved everywhere by the Coulomb solution and one can say that the source of the Coulomb field is a point-like electric charge. The solution, however, is not completely consistent since the equations of motion of the charged particle
> in its own electric field are not solved because this diverges at the position of the particle. This is a well-known problem of the classical model of the electron that the quantum theory solves.  "*

How does the quantum theory solve this problem? Is there a way to give intuition behind the singularity of coulomb potential at the point where the point-like charge rests?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know the answer about how quantum mechanics solves it. I can give you half an answer and clarify the issue we have:

The problem is that the potential diverges as we go to the location of the original charge under consideration. Assume a unit-charge object goes from distance R all the way to the point of the original charge itself. The work done, $\int F dr$, is the potential for that original charge. This diverges, because the force (and hence “field”) diverges at $r=0$.

$$F=\frac{kq}{r^2} ~, ~ \int_{0}^R F dr = kq/0 - kq/R$$

This is why electric potential is always defined relative to a reference position r_ref (a vector, a position in space. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_potential_energy )

Both electric field and potential (but especially field) are really imaginary tools for calculation based only on coulombs law. It’s just that a variety of point charge configurations can give the same resultant force per unit charge somewhere, and the idea of a field at that spot seems reasonable and is enormously useful and tractable.

If the charged particle has a finite radius (as I would guess most thing do ), then the potential to bring even a dimensionless point unit-charge to it is defined. And bringing two particles with finite radii together is as well. I can intuitively sense how quantum mechanics might solve this by having clouds of charges and never have two point charges coincide in space.

I’ve never understood the so-called problem of an electron and its own field (self-field) and its self-potential being a problem, probably because of how I view field and potential, as tools, and as defined as I do. (Note: Not that this problem is exactly identical to the one youre describing, but it is similar and has been brought up before.) What does it mean to bring an electron to itself, or have it be affected by its own field. To my understanding of field, that is the same as asking what it means for it to repel itself by coulomb’s law. I’ve sensed that such self-inconsistencies stem from a lack of understanding of fields and potential. They usually come from philosophy-of-science types. I can’t imagine a physicist having this last issue I’m describing, and perhaps not even the one you quoted about.